# How to use mix link Multi-CPU of parallel computing in chainer v2.1.0

Tags: chainer

In my research . I wrote 2 layers in neural network, the bottom first layer is RNN which runs on GPU, the top second layer is CPU(the algorithm model nature is more suited to CPU), I implemented it in CPU in chainer self-defined Link.

But, the CPU layer is slow , I can't wait for deadline of my paper submit. So I want to use parallel computing of this layer.

What is the best practice and fast way to implement parallel this link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ChainerMN (not Chainer) does not support a direct way to accelerate computation within a single layer.

I would recommend to consider the following options.

- Use GPU for the "CPU-friendly" layer as well
- Use Cython or other acceleration technologies
- Use multithreading on CPU

Thanks.

Comment: 2, Use GPU for the "CPU-friendly" layer as well? what does it mean?

Comment: I have already implemented in Cython, but the core logic is numpy computation inside a big for-loop. Numpy computation seems cannot without gil, thus I attempt to use cython prange(multi-thread parallel for-loop) failed.

Comment: I have many training samples, Can I use chainerMN to data parallel training? each cpu train one sample, then wait for all CPU done, sum up to calculate overall gradient?

Comment: I have no idea what "CPU-friendly" actually means. So I suggested to convert the algorithm or somehow port the code to GPUs. You didn't provide enough information to answer. Do not provide information little by little.

Comment: If the main logic is in numpy, you may use CuPy.

Comment: As of now, ChainerMN does not provide a layer-wise data parallel computation.

Comment: You said you have "many" data, which generally means it's GPU friendly. what made you think it's "CPU-friendly" ? Again, you should provide enough information to answer.

Comment: My self layer algorithm is that it is a big for loop,  inside the big loop, there is  a lot of matrix computation, each matrix is 626 x 626, then we do np.dot, thats two big matrix multiply, but because of for loop nature, and because of two 626 x 626 matrix is not fit into GPU memory. Therefore I implemented it in CPU layer.

Comment: Hmm. (I don't think 626x626 matrix is too large for GPU memory, but I guess you mean there's a lot of them and the total size is large). If you have many training samples and you think you can use data parallel approach, then you may want to consider making the whole model data parallel, which means to use smaller minibatch size and run the training in a data parallel way. If it's impossible, unfortunately, it's not straightforward.

Comment: how to use cpu mode data parallel ，do you have 安example code？ I think for-loop of matrix computation is not suited for GPU

Comment: Can you provide some data parallel example code of chainer? Thank you very very much!

Comment: I have experiment cupy on a 200 x 200 matrix computation but it is slower than numpy , I think cupy may not appropriate for inside for-loop to compute a lot of small matrix